# How can I find the error which causes a red cross on the project's icon in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I create a simple Maven project in eclipse using m2elipse plugin, then I revise the pom.xml to what I need and save it. After the rebuilding of the project, there's **a red cross on my project's icon, but with no red cross anywhere else in this project**. According to my experience, this is caused by the **java building path** or **library reference**, so how can I find this out? because the library reference is auto produced by maven. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the listing of all errors and warnings, open the problems view.

Answer (score 0):

You must upgrade the m2e connector. It's a known bug, but there is a solution

Into Eclipse click "Help" > "Install new Software..."

Appears a window. In the "Install" windows:

2a. Into the input box "Work with", enter next site location and press Enter https://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/1.4/

2b. Appears a lot of information into "Name" input box. Select all the items

2c. Click the "Next" button.

Finish the installation and restart Eclipse.

The root cause here is maven connector, you need to upgrade the connector.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can open the **Problem View** which is highlighted by another user @konstantin in his answer.

Select the pom.xml which is having the red cross on it and open this.

[image]

and then you will be able to see it like below

[image]